# How to ignore keyboard strokes/disable the keyboard temporarily?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making a game in python 2.7 and I have a lot of `raw_inputs()` to ask certain questions like what is your name. I have also got `time.sleep()` before a lot of `raw_inputs()` and if you press enter while `time.sleep()` is being executed then the `raw_input()` thinks that the enter keystroke was your response. Is there a way to ignore keyboard presses or disable the keyboard temporarily until I need it? I am coding on repl.it by the way.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
def keyboard_disable():
  stuff that disables the keyboard

def keyboard_enable():
  stuff that enables the keyboard

#previous game code
keyboard_disable()
time.sleep(3)
keyboard_enable()
name = raw_input("What is your name: ")
```

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034297/ignore-keyboard-input-in-python-while-sleeping

Other relevant discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/dldnjWRX3lE%5B1-25%5D

Comment: Why make your program sleep at all? If it's to create the illusion that the program is very smart and thinking about my response, I think a fast program looks smarter than a slow one. If it's to give the user a break between inputs, the fact that the user is impatiently typing in between prompts is proof that they do not want a break.

Comment: @Kevin I'm using the time.sleep() function to give the user time to read instructions and rules etc before moving on.

Comment: But if you print the instructions and then call `name = raw_input("What is your name: ")` right afterwards with no intervening sleep(), it's not as though the user will be unable to read the instructions one line above the prompt. Or are you saying "my instructions are several pages long so I want to output them slowly enough that the user won't have to scroll up to read them all"? That seems like an inexact science, since you can't know how fast your users can read. I've seen lots of programs with very long `--help` outputs that trust the users to know how to use a scroll bar.